# how to get angularjs component to render related template when imported into module

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I was wondering if someone can help with setting up angularjs with webpack as shown here: https://pastebin.com/dptjwHxp

The file structure is as follows

```
root
 |____public
 |     |____index.html
 |
 |____client
        |____________components
        |                |
        |____index.js    |_______app.js
```

The current configuration I'm trying to get to "work" (by which I mean having the content in the app component's template to render) is as follows:

++++ client/index.js

```
import angular from "angular";
import app from "./components/app";

export default angular.module("practice", []);
```

++++ client/components/app.js

```
import angular from "angular";

export default angular.module("practice", []).component("app", {
  template: "<div>This needs to show up!!</div>"
});
```

++++ public/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <body ng-app="practice" >
        <h1>Angular Practice</h1>
        <app></app>
        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The funny thing is that I can get the app component to render just fine if the code isn't in its own separate component app.js file with index.js as follows:

```
import angular from "angular";

export default angular.module("practice", []).component("app", {
  template: "<div>This needs to show up!!</div>"
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-creating the angular.module pratice when you pass params to the function.

Should be:

export default angular.module("practice").component("app", {})

Comment: which part of the code needs to be changed to `export default angular.module("practice").component("app", {})`? Thanks.

Comment: Your component declaration.